# Error while inserting data from xls file into SQLite android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, parsing, apache-poi

I'm trying to add all rows from xls-parser to my sqlite DB.
It works well for first half of table, but rest send me this error for the all rows that are not added:

```
10-22 20:43:32.453  17882-17882/? E/Database﹕ Error inserting null= diameter= category=Постное Меню price=180.0 weight=220.0 subcategory=Салаты name=Микс овощной composition=микс из листьев салата, черри, болгпрский перец, авокадо, кедроаые орешки, пармезан, зелень, ореховая заправка type=Уно Моменто url=http://epongorod.ru/images/stories/virtuemart/product/uno-miks-ovoshchnoj.jpg
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO menuTable(null, diameter, category, price, weight, subcategory, name, composition, type, url) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1536)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
        at com.epon.MainActivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:158)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sample of parsing:

```
if (wb != null) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int cn=row.getFirstCellNum(); cn<row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                String result = cell.toString();

                String name = null;
                switch (cn) {
                    case 0:
                        name = "type";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        name = "category";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        name = "subcategory";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        name = "name";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        name = "composition";
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        name = "weight";
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        name = "diameter";
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        name = "price";
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        name = "url";
                        break;
                }
                cv.put(name, result);
            }

            db.insert("menuTable", null, cv);
        }
```

and here is code of creating the table:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + "menuTable" + " (" +
                "_id" + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "type" + "TEXT," +
                "category" + "TEXT," +
                "subcategory" + "TEXT," +
                "name" + "TEXT," +
                "composition" + "TEXT," +
                "weight" + "TEXT," +
                "diameter" + "TEXT," +
                "price" + "TEXT," +
                "url" + "TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

So, I have only half of full table.

Comment: name isn't being set and is resulting in one of your keys in your ContentValues to be null. Likely your count variable is going over 8 or under 0 which you don't account for.

Comment: @dymmeh Why does it work for 200 rows then?

Comment: I have no idea since I'm not sure whats in your file. `INSERT INTO menuTable(null, ` The null is a key which means "name" was never set properly. Put a case statement for if (name == null)  and put a breakpoint inside.. When it hits that breakpoint inspect your data to see what the contents of your row is and why suddenly name is null.

Comment: apparently, at some point there are more than 9 cells in a row.

Comment: @dymmeh Edited, but have the same problem.

Comment: @njzk2 still the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is Java's way of telling you that SQLite won't accept the [SQLite Keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) **null** as the name of a column in your code-generated INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO menuTable(null, diameter, category, price, weight, subcategory, name, composition, type, url) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Hard to guess with just what you've shared here, but perhaps completing your code like this:

```
                case 8:
                    name = "url";
                    break;

                default:
                    //name = "_id";
                    break;
            }

            if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
                cv.put(name, result);
            }

        }

        db.insert("menuTable", null, cv);
    }
}
```

will cover all the switch "possibilities" and name variable "unknowns" more completely?